# Price is being displayed with to many zeros eg 15.8900

Tags: price

I have created a block of code that will show a row of products if the user doesn't hit the free delivery limit. My only problem is the way the price is being displayed. it shows it like £34.9900 instead of just £39.99 like it does on every other page.

This is my line of code that shows the price

```
<p class="upsell_pro_price"><?php echo $_product->getPrice();?></a></p>
```

If you know why this is doing this and can help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the Magento Price format helper which formats the price according to the store configuration:

```
Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($_product->getPrice());
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use PHP to format your price. you can use the code like

`number_format($_product->getPrice(), 2, '.', '')`

It will display price upto 2 digits.

**[Edit]**

I think using Magento Format price functionality will be better option. I answered it in a  hurry over viewing the top level problem of number formatting.

You should use instead

`Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($_product->getPrice());`

Comment: thank you, when it will let me i will accept your answer, thanks again

Comment: @Dexter you should really utilise the built in Magento functionality in the form of **formatPrice()**

Comment: @Dave: Yes you are right Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($_product->getPrice()); too is a better option

Comment: ok cheers, i have changed it now :)